# What is the correct character encoding for the following

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, iso

im having a string like this which im trying to save to my mysql database

```
$str = "The size id 9” x 12” and some other";
```

here the `”` is not the regular `"`

Its a part of an Ajax response,In the php side this is what im using

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
echo $this->_helper->json(array("string is" => $str));
```

My but console shows 9[a sqaure box] x 12[a square box] //actually a square box cant able to paste it

And im saving this string to my database which has the charset `utf8mb4` which is also not correct (ignores the ” in the table while saving)

Can somebody show me which charset i need to use for both showing in html and saving in mysql

Comment: Most character encodings will do the job. Any Unicode encoding definitely will do the job. The trick is using it properly from end to end.

Answer (score 0):

`utf8_encode` will do the trick.

Then `utf8_decode` when you print.